Buildroot: wpa_supplicant cannot connect to ESP32 SoftAP
I have a SoftAP set up using ESP32-S3. Clean example from ESP-IDF SDK, no changes on my end. I also have a MilkV-Duo board running buildroot with RTL8188 network card over USB. Here's the state of things:
X
I have a SoftAP set up using ESP32-S3. Clean example from ESP-IDF SDK, no changes on my end. I also have a MilkV-Duo board running buildroot with RTL8188 network card over USB. Here's the state of things:
ESP32 SoftAP:
SSID: myssid
Password: mypassword

My phone  (iPhone 8) can connect to ESP32 AP
My laptop (Windows 11 Asus TUF F15) can connect to ESP32 AP
MilkV-Duo can connect to my home network, my phone hotspot, etc
MilkV-Duo won't connect to the ESP32 SoftAP

wpa_supplicant.conf from MilkV-Duo: (I changed my actual passwords, don't worry)
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ap_scan=1
update_config=1

network={
  ssid="ASUS1200"
  psk="12345678"
  id_str="ASUS1200"
  priority=2
}

network={
  ssid="cheap-Extender"
  psk="cheapextender11"
  id_str="extender"
  priority=1
}

network={
  ssid="myssid"
  psk="mypassword"
  id_str="myssid"
  priority=3
}

network={
  bssid=34:85:18:9d:6b:c9
  #psk="mypassword"
  psk=35d560c7453f32cebc6ec7b39bfbdca37e3a245ba028dc9dd33dcc0ddc22121a
  ssid="myssid"
  scan_ssid=1
  id_str="myssid-mac"
}

network={
  ssid="myssid"
  id_str="myssid-psk"
  #psk="mypassword"
  psk=2f0568b3492812bd56b946dbaf3fd7dd669b9a4602a09aa6462ff057949b025c
}


When I use wpa_cli tool I get the following results:
[root@milkv-duo]~# wpa_cli
wpa_cli v2.9
Copyright (c) 2004-2019, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors

This software may be distributed under the terms of the BSD license.
See README for more details.


Selected interface 'wlan0'

Interactive mode

> scan
OK
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>CTRL-EVENT-NETWORK-NOT-FOUND
> scan_results
> bssid / frequency / signal level / flags / ssid
34:85:18:9d:6b:c9       2412    -14     [WPA2-PSK-SHA256-CCMP][ESS]     myssid


So it clearly sees the network, however, no matter what I do (add_network, set_network X ssid, set_network X psk, enable_network, select_network, etc) it just won't connect to it, while it easily and quickly  connects to my home network whenever I turn it on. I'll appreciate any help.
